# ISupportIncrementalLoading last two items show incorrectly in UI

Tags: c#, xaml, listview

I'm having problems with displaying last two items fetched from the server.

I have a next code:

```
public class NotificationsToShow : ObservableCollection<Notification>, ISupportIncrementalLoading
        {
            public bool lastItem = false;

            public bool HasMoreItems
            {
                get
                {
                    return !lastItem;
                }
            }

            public IAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult> LoadMoreItemsAsync(uint count)
            {
                CoreDispatcher coreDispatcher = Window.Current.Dispatcher;

                return Task.Run<LoadMoreItemsResult>(async () =>
                {
                    await coreDispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                    () =>
                    {
                        NavigationManager.Instance.IsApplicationBusy = true;
                    });

                    // HERE I REQUEST DATA FROM MY SERVER
                    List<Notification> items = await ServiceManager.Instance.GetNotificationsAsync(this.Count, 20);
                    if (items == null || items.Count == 0 || items.Count < 19)
                    {
                        // IF RETURNED is NULL or COUNT is ZERO or Count is smaller than requested amout then those were the last items. Set the flag
                        lastItem = true;
                    }

                    await coreDispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                        () =>
                        {
                            foreach (Notification item in items)
                            {
                                this.Add(item);
                            }

                            NavigationManager.Instance.IsApplicationBusy = false;
                        });

                    return new LoadMoreItemsResult() { Count = (uint)this.Count };

                }).AsAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult>();
            }
        }
```

And i have a next output on the UI:

Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
...
Item 59
Item 2   **<=== Why?**
Item 3   **<=== Why?**

In debugger i see my array in THIS and it is correct:

Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
...
Item 59
Item 60
Item 61

**Where is my mistake here?**

On smaller screens i have this issue reproducing on 50% of items.